# using a variable to send parameters to IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure. In this procedure there's a piece of code that look like

```
...WHERE someParam IN (1,2)...
```

I should abstract this part, cause an undefined numer of parameters should be considered (not only 1 OR 2). I get this parameter list from vb.net code as a cvs string (i.e. "1,2" or "78, 109" and so on). Pratically my situation will be something like that:

```
DECLARE @IdParam varchar(100)
SET @IdParam = '1,2'
...
...WHERE someParam IN (@IdParm)...
```

but this code will clearly produce me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type
>   int.

What can I do to reach my goal and keep SQL engine quiet? If an optimal solution exist I could consider to modify prexisten VB code.

**Edit 1: I wouldn't use that ugly solution of the linked post!**

Comment: You will need to use a function that split the string into table variable and use that table variable in the query

Comment: I would recommend against TVP, it's very slow.

Comment: @FabianBigler: compared to an iterative split function?

Comment: @FabianBigler What is this based on?  According to the SQLCAT team, TVP is the fastest way to move data into SQL Server from a Client App.

Comment: I tested this a while back. But frankly, I would need to doublecheck, if this applied to all scenarios.
 Jeff also confirms this in the related link
"we tested this and table valued parameters are DOG slow. It is literally faster to execute 5 queries than it is to do one TVP."

Comment: TVP is certainly an alternative, but the OP said he is getting a comma delimited string, so that influenced my answer.

Comment: I'm ready to change the visual basic code if a better solution exist...

Comment: @FabianBigler With all due respect to Jeff, without any code to validate that statement against, I'm going to have to go with the SQLCAT team, given that they hold the world's record for Insert speed on any DBMS.

Comment: @RBarryYoung sure thing. maybe there is no better option at the moment for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to send in multiple values.

```
CREATE PROC foo
   @IDList SomeType READONLY
AS
...
    WHERE someParam IN (SELECT ID FROM @IDList )
...
GO
```

Comment: I have SQL SERVER 2005

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to turn the string into a list...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MVParamToInt](@RepParam nvarchar(max), @Delim char(1)= ',')
RETURNS @VALUES TABLE (Param int)AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @chrind INT
   DECLARE @Piece nvarchar(max)
   SELECT @chrind = 1
   WHILE @chrind > 0
      BEGIN
         SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim,@RepParam)
         IF @chrind > 0
            SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@RepParam,@chrind - 1)
         ELSE
            SELECT @Piece = @RepParam

         IF ISNUMERIC(@Piece) = 1
            INSERT @VALUES(Param) VALUES(CAST(@Piece AS int))

         SELECT @RepParam = RIGHT(@RepParam,LEN(@RepParam) - @chrind)
         IF LEN(@RepParam) = 0 BREAK
      END
   RETURN
END
```

Then your query becomes something like...

```
...WHERE mycolumn IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParamToInt(yourstring, '.'))
```